# ¿Como poner elemento en xquery?

Tags: xquery

Como hacer consulta en xquery para que salga así.

```
`<personas provincia="Málaga">
               <persona cod="AB06">Domínguez Banderas, José Antonio</persona>
               <persona cod="MA48">Flores González, Josefa</persona>
               <persona cod="PA89">Moreno de Alborán Ferrándiz, Pablo</persona>
               <persona cod="DR80">Rovira de Rivas, Daniel</persona>
</personas>`
```

Alguien que me de una solución para la consulta de Xquery.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer una consulta en Xquery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/592829/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-una-consulta-en-xquery)