# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en Xquery?

Tags: xquery

**Como hacer que esta consulta en Xquery**
Se desea mostrar los nombres y apellidos de aquellos personajes de la base de datos, nacidos en la provincia de Málaga y que actualmente están vivos (i.e. no tienen fecha de defunción), de forma ordenada por los apellidos.
El formato de salida debe ser un fragmento de xml respetando los nombres de los elementos y atributos siguientes:

**Aparezca así**

```
    `\<personas provincia="Málaga"\>
            \<persona cod="AB06"\>Domínguez Banderas, José Antonio\</persona\>
            \<persona cod="MA48"\>Flores González, Josefa\</persona\>
            \<persona cod="PA89"\>Moreno de Alborán Ferrándiz, Pablo\</persona\>
            \<persona cod="DR80"\>Rovira de Rivas, Daniel\</persona\>
     \</personas\>`
```

**Mi consulta es esta**

````
      ```\<personajes provincia="Malaga"\>

         {for $per in doc("personajes.xml")/personajes/personaje

         where $per/provincia = "Málaga" and not($per/fecha_defuncion)

         order by $per/apellidos 

         return \<personaje cod="{$per/@cod}"\>{concat( $per/apellidos, "," 
         ,$per/nombre)}\</personaje\>}

         \</personajes\>```
````

**El archivo xml es este**

````
  ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!-- Datos generados por P.Lluyot para la Tarea 06 de LM
      No toda la información reflejada en este xml tiene por qué ser correcta,
       algunos datos pueden ser ficticios -->
     <personajes>
          <personaje cod="PP01">
            <nombre>Pablo</nombre>
            <apellidos>Ruiz Picasso</apellidos>
            <alias>Pablo Picasso</alias>
            <fecha_nacimiento>1881-10-25</fecha_nacimiento>
            <fecha_defuncion>1973-04-08</fecha_defuncion>
            <localidad>Málaga</localidad>
            <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
            <oficio>Pintor, Escultor</oficio>
     </personaje>
         <personaje cod="AM03">
           <nombre>Antonio</nombre>
           <apellidos>Machado Ruiz</apellidos>
    <alias>Antonio Machado</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1875-07-26</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1939-02-22</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Poeta</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="FG11">
    <nombre>Federico</nombre>
    <apellidos>García Lorca</apellidos>
    <alias>Federico García Lorca</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1898-06-05</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1936-08-18</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Fuente Vaqueros</localidad>
    <provincia>Granada</provincia>
    <oficio>Poeta, Dramaturgo, Prosista</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="IP07">
    <nombre>María Isabel</nombre>
    <apellidos>Pantoja Martín</apellidos>
    <alias>Isabel Pantoja</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1956-08-02</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantante</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="MZ09">
    <nombre>María</nombre>
    <apellidos>Zambrano Alarcón</apellidos>
    <alias>María Zambrano</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1904-04-22</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1991-02-06</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Vélez-Málaga</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Filósofa</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="LG09">
    <nombre>Luis</nombre>
    <apellidos>Rodríguez Gordillo</apellidos>
    <alias>Luis Gordillo</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1934-12-27</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Pintor, Artista</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="AB06">
    <nombre>José Antonio</nombre>
    <apellidos>Domínguez Banderas</apellidos>
    <alias>Antonio Banderas</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1960-08-10</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Málaga</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Actor, Cantante, Productor, Director, Empresario</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="EM10">
    <nombre>Estrella de la Aurora</nombre>
    <apellidos>Morente Carbonell</apellidos>
    <alias>Estrella Morente</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1980-08-14</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Las Gabias</localidad>
    <provincia>Granada</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaora</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="JM09">
    <nombre>José</nombre>
    <apellidos>Soto Soto</apellidos>
    <alias>José Mercé</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1955-04-07</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Jerez de la Frontera</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="JP02">
    <nombre>José Luis</nombre>
    <apellidos>Perales Morillas</apellidos>
    <alias>José Luis Perales</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1945-01-18</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Castejón</localidad>
    <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantautor, Productor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="JC07">
    <nombre>Joaquín</nombre>
    <apellidos>Pedraja Reyes</apellidos>
    <alias>Joaquín Cortés</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1969-02-22</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Córdoba</localidad>
    <provincia>Córdoba</provincia>
    <oficio>Bailaor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="CL01">
    <nombre>Carmen</nombre>
    <apellidos>Pacheco Rodríguez</apellidos>
    <alias>Carmen Linares</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1951-08-25</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Linares</localidad>
    <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaora</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="MJ31">
    <nombre>María</nombre>
    <apellidos>Jiménez Gallego</apellidos>
    <alias>María Jiménez</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1950-02-03</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantante, Bailaora, Actriz</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="NP01">
    <nombre>María Rosa</nombre>
    <apellidos>García García</apellidos>
    <alias>Niña Pastori</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1977-01-15</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>San Fernando</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaora</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="JR02">
    <nombre>Juan Ramón</nombre>
    <apellidos>Jiménez Mantecón</apellidos>
    <alias>Juan Ramón Jiménez</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1881-12-23</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1958-05-29</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Moguer</localidad>
    <provincia>Huelva</provincia>
    <oficio>Escritor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="RA01">
    <nombre>Rafael</nombre>
    <apellidos>Alberti Merello</apellidos>
    <alias>Rafael Alberti</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1902-12-16</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1999-10-28</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>El Puerto de Santa María</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Escritor, Poeta</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="AB43">
    <nombre>Antonio</nombre>
    <apellidos>Burgos Belinchón</apellidos>
    <alias>Antonio Burgos</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1943-06-30</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Periodista, Escritor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="AS68">
    <nombre>Alejandro</nombre>
    <apellidos>Sánchez Pizarro</apellidos>
    <alias>Alejandro Sanz</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1968-12-18</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    <provincia>Madrid</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantautor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="PA89">
    <nombre>Pablo</nombre>
    <apellidos>Moreno de Alborán Ferrándiz</apellidos>
    <alias>Pablo Alborán</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1989-05-31</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Málaga</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantautor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="DR80">
    <nombre>Daniel</nombre>
    <apellidos>Rovira de Rivas</apellidos>
    <alias>Dani Rovira</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1980-11-01</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Málaga</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Actor, Comediante</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="JEG48">
    <nombre>Juan</nombre>
    <apellidos>Eslava Galán</apellidos>
    <alias>Juan Eslava Galán</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1948-03-07</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Arjona</localidad>
    <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    <oficio>Escritor</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="AG60">
    <nombre>María Almudena</nombre>
    <apellidos>Grandes Hernández</apellidos>
    <alias>Almudena Grandes</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1960-05-07</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>2021-11-27</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    <provincia>Madrid</provincia>
    <oficio>Escritora</oficio>
</personaje>
<personaje cod="AB01">
    <nombre>Antonio</nombre>
    <apellidos>Gala Velasco</apellidos>
    <alias>Antonio Gala</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1936-10-02</fecha_nacimiento>  
    <localidad>Brazatortas</localidad>
    <provincia>Ciudad Real</provincia>
    <oficio>Escritor, Dramaturgo</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="JR01">
    <nombre>Julio</nombre>
    <apellidos>Romero de Torres</apellidos>
    <alias>Julio Romero de Torres</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1874-11-09</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1930-05-10</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Córdoba</localidad>
    <provincia>Córdoba</provincia>
    <oficio>Pintor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="VK01">
    <nombre>Victoria</nombre>
    <apellidos>Kent</apellidos>
    <alias>Victoria Kent Siano</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1892-03-03</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1987-09-22</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Málaga</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Abogada, Política</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="BI01">
    <nombre>Blas</nombre>
    <apellidos>Infante Pérez de Vargas</apellidos>
    <alias>Blas Infante</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1885-07-05</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1936-08-11</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Casares</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Político, Escritor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="PL01">
    <nombre>Francisco</nombre>
    <apellidos>Sánchez Gómez</apellidos>
    <alias>Paco de Lucía</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1947-12-21</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>2014-02-25</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Algeciras</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Guitarrista</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="CI01">
    <nombre>José</nombre>
    <apellidos>Monge Cruz</apellidos>
    <alias>Camarón de la Isla</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1950-12-05</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1992-07-02</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>San Fernando</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="LF23">
    <nombre>Dolores</nombre>
    <apellidos>Flores Ruiz</apellidos>
    <alias>Lola Flores</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1923-01-21</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1995-05-16</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Jerez de la Frontera</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaora, Actriz</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="ME31">
    <nombre>Manuel</nombre>
    <apellidos>García Escobar</apellidos>
    <alias>Manolo Escobar</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1931-10-19</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>2013-10-24</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>El Ejido</localidad>
    <provincia>Almería</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantante, Actor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="MA48">
    <nombre>Josefa</nombre>
    <apellidos>Flores González</apellidos>
    <alias>Marisol</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1948-02-04</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Málaga</localidad>
    <provincia>Málaga</provincia>
    <oficio>Actriz, Cantante</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="EF37">
    <nombre>José Luis</nombre>
    <apellidos>Cantero Rada</apellidos>
    <alias>El Fary</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1937-08-20</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>2007-06-19</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    <provincia>Madrid</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantante, Actor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="LG21">
    <nombre>Dolores</nombre>
    <apellidos>Gaos González-Pola</apellidos>
    <alias>Lola Gaos</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1921-06-09</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1993-07-02</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Valencia</localidad>
    <provincia>Valencia</provincia>
    <oficio>Actriz</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="CS30">
    <nombre>María del Carmen</nombre>
    <apellidos>García Galisteo</apellidos>
    <alias>Carmen Sevilla</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1930-10-16</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Actriz, Cantante</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="CC46">
    <nombre>José Carlos</nombre>
    <apellidos>Cano Fernández</apellidos>
    <alias>Carlos Cano</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1946-01-28</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>2000-12-19</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Granada</localidad>
    <provincia>Granada</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantautor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="JS04">
    <nombre>Joaquín Ramón</nombre>
    <apellidos>Martínez Sabina</apellidos>
    <alias>Joaquín Sabina</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1949-02-12</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Úbeda</localidad>
    <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantautor y Poeta</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="BE70">
    <nombre>José Luis</nombre>
    <apellidos>Figuereo Franco</apellidos>
    <alias>Selu (El Barrio)</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1970-06-04</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Cádiz</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantautor</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="RA62">
    <nombre>María Dolores</nombre>
    <apellidos>Amaya Vega</apellidos>
    <alias>Remedios Amaya</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1962-08-01</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaora</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="RJ46">
    <nombre>María del Rocío</nombre>
    <apellidos>Mohedano Jurado</apellidos>
    <alias>Rocío Jurado</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1946-09-18</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>2006-06-01</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Chipiona</localidad>
    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    <oficio>Cantaora y Actriz</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="LC02">
    <nombre>Luis</nombre>
    <apellidos>Cernuda Bidou</apellidos>
    <alias>Luis Cernuda</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1902-09-21</fecha_nacimiento>
    <fecha_defuncion>1963-11-05</fecha_defuncion>
    <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
    <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    <oficio>Poeta</oficio>
</personaje>

<personaje cod="MM56">
    <nombre>Antonio</nombre>
    <apellidos>Muñoz Molina</apellidos>
    <alias>Antonio Muñoz Molina</alias>
    <fecha_nacimiento>1956-01-10</fecha_nacimiento>
    
    <localidad>Úbeda</localidad>
    <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    <oficio>Escritor</oficio>
</personaje>
````

```

Quiero saber como poner esa consulta para que me aparezca así como pongo aquí abajo.

```
        `\<personas provincia="Málaga"\>
             \<persona cod="AB06"\>Domínguez Banderas, José Antonio\</persona\>
             \<persona cod="MA48"\>Flores González, Josefa\</persona\>
             \<persona cod="PA89"\>Moreno de Alborán Ferrándiz, Pablo\</persona\>
             \<persona cod="DR80"\>Rovira de Rivas, Daniel\</persona\>
         \</personas\>`
```

Comment: Mi consulta es orientadora ya que no me aparece como exige el ejercicio.

Answer (score 0):

Esta query puede recuperar los resultados que buscas en el formato requerido:

```
<personas provincia="Málaga">
{
  for $p in doc("personajes.xml")/personajes/personaje[provincia = "Málaga" and not(fecha_defuncion)]
  return <persona cod="{$p/@cod}">{concat($p/apellidos, ', ', $p/nombre)}</persona>
}
</personas>
```

Sólo necesitas definir una etiqueta externa  con el atributo requerido para que se convierta en el elemento parent del resultado de salida. En su interior, abres llaves {} para generar contenido **dinámicamente** mediante una expresión XQuery que emplea un bucle **for** y define las **condiciones** que habías aplicado correctamente en tu intento.

En la cláusula return se construye en cada iteración un nuevo elemento  para cada personaje en el documento que cumpla las condiciones, cuyo contenido es la **concatenación** de los valores de los nodos  y  más una coma y un espacio.

He asumido que las barras invertidas o *backslashes* **** que reflejas en la salida esperada no son intencionados, sino meramente caracteres de escape que han aparecido cuando has pegado el contenido en esta página.

Comment: Hola Alejandro tu consulta no me vale.

Comment: Ya la he probado y nada.

Answer (score 0):

Me faltaba darle a la opción Editor y pulsar indent result para que me indexara la respuesta.   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes confirmar qué consulta te ha funcionado al aplicar la indentación? ¿Tu consulta original?